# Big-O for a polynomial in log equation?

Tags: big-o

Could you please help me to find the big Oh notation for this : log(n^n+n)+n and why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**log(n^n + n) <= log(2*n^n) = log2 + log(n^n)**
Besides **log(n^n) = nlog(n)**.

**nlog(n) + n + log2** is obviously **O(nlog(n))**